# Объединить ассоциативный массив на основе ключей

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет. Мне нужно из массива

```
$array = [
    [
        "module" => "articles",
        "read" => true,
        "edit" => false,
        "create" => false,
        "delete" => false,
    ], [
        "module" => "articles",
        "read" => false,
        "edit" => false,
        "create" => true,
        "delete" => false,
    ], [
        "module" => "articles",
        "read" => false,
        "edit" => true,
        "create" => false,
        "delete" => false,
    ], [
        "module" => "user",
        "read" => true,
        "edit" => false,
        "create" => false,
        "delete" => false,
    ], [
        "module" => "user",
        "read" => false,
        "edit" => false,
        "create" => true,
        "delete" => false,
    ]
];
```

получить такой массив

```
$result = [
    [
        "module" => "articles",
        "read" => true,
        "edit" => true,
        "create" => true,
        "delete" => false,
    ], [
        "module" => "users",
        "read" => true,
        "edit" => false,
        "create" => true,
        "delete" => false,
    ],
];
```

т.е. если при объединении один из ключей массива отсутствует, то он false.

Пока что написал такой код, он только объединяет

```
$result = array_reduce($rows, function($accumulator, $item) {
    $index = $item['module'];
    if (!isset($accumulator[$index])) {
        $accumulator[$index] = [
            "module" => $index,
            "read" => $item['read'],
            "edit" => $item['edit'],
            "create" => $item['create'],
            "delete" => $item['delete'],
        ];
    }
    array_intersect_key(
        $accumulator, $item
    );

    return $accumulator;
});
```

Comment: `при объединении один из ключей массива отсутствует` - можно этот момент прояснить?  В приведённых массивах одинаковый набор ключей у элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть, то атрибуты объединяются по дизъюнкции (логическое ИЛИ).
В таком случае, немного подправив Ваш код, получим нужный результат:

```php
$result = array_reduce($array, function($acc, $item) {
    $index = $item['module'];
        
    if (!isset($acc[$index])) $acc[$index] = $item;
    else
        foreach($item as $k => $v)
            if($k !== 'module')
                $acc[$index][$k] = !empty($acc[$index][$k]) || $v;

    return $acc;
});

$result = array_values($result); //если требуется индексный массив
```

Comment: дефицит скобок фигурных в стране? ) зы: 1) в цикле лучше явно указать поля 2) `!empty()` убрать, и просто оставить `||` 3) в начале проверку имхо лучше заменить на `array_key_exists`

Comment: @teran Не вижу необходимости в дополнительных фигурных скобках. Это дело предпочтений, кому дефицит, а кому лишние. 1) Лучше кому? Все зависит от требований. 2) Не согласен. Читайте вопрос, если атрибут отсутствует, принять за false. 3) В целом согласен, но возможны требования, при которых может оказаться как раз наоборот.

Comment: @teran Странно, что при всех замечаниях, Вас не смутило `$index = $item['module'];` ;)

Comment: а чем оно меня должно было смутить? проверить наличие ключа? это чрезмерно для условия задачи. дана явная структура данных, которую надо понимать как 100% соответствующую.  не надо играть в угадайку и проверять все подряд.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот, это очень не логический код, но помог как мог)

```
$array = [
    [
        "module" => "articles",
        "read" => true,
        "edit" => false,
        "create" => false,
        "delete" => false,
    ], [
        "module" => "articles",
        "read" => false,
        "edit" => false,
        "create" => true,
        "delete" => false,
    ], [
        "module" => "articles",
        "read" => false,
        "edit" => true,
        "create" => false,
        "delete" => false,
    ], [
        "module" => "user",
        "read" => true,
        "edit" => false,
        "create" => false,
        "delete" => false,
    ], [
        "module" => "user",
        "read" => false,
        "edit" => false,
        "create" => true,
        "delete" => false,
    ]
];

$newArray = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $module = $array[$i]["module"];

    if (!isset($newArray[$module])) {
        $newArray[$module] = $array[$i];
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    foreach($newArray as $key => $value) {
        if ($array[$i]["module"] == $value["module"]) {
            $newArray[$key]["read"] = $array[$i]["read"] == true ? true : $newArray[$key]["read"];
            $newArray[$key]["edit"] = $array[$i]["edit"] == true ? true : $newArray[$key]["edit"];
            $newArray[$key]["create"] = $array[$i]["create"] == true ? true : $newArray[$key]["create"];
            $newArray[$key]["delete"] = $array[$i]["delete"] == true ? true : $newArray[$key]["delete"];
        }
    }
}
var_dump($newArray);
```